# How to combine two CTE's in to single select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i am trying to combine two CTE expressions in to single as they both have almost same join tables. How can i achieve this?. your comments are so valuable.

```
SELECT  wf.WorkflowID
            ,COALESCE(STUFF((
            SELECT distinct ''; '', '''' + cOPF.WorkflowLinkID
            FROM Client_1_Workflow mopf`enter code here`
            join Client_1_Workflow_Cell cOPF WITH(NOLOCK) on mopf.WorkflowID = cOPF.WorkflowLinkID
            join Client_1_Workflow iwf WITH(NOLOCK) on cOPF.WorkflowID = wf.WorkflowID
            where iwf.WorkflowID = wf.WorkflowID 
            FOR XML PATH(''''),TYPE).value(''(./text())[1]'',''VARCHAR(MAX)''),1,1,''''),'''') AS WorkflowID
            from Client_1_Workflow   wf WITH(NOLOCK) 


SELECT  wf.WorkflowID
            ,COALESCE(STUFF((
            SELECT distinct ''; '', '''' +mopfn.WorkflowName
            FROM Client_1_Workflow mopfn
            join Client_1_Workflow_Cell cOPF WITH(NOLOCK) on mopfn.WorkflowID = cOPF.WorkflowLinkID
            join Client_1_Workflow iwf WITH(NOLOCK) on cOPF.WorkflowID = wf.WorkflowID
            where iwf.WorkflowID = wf.WorkflowID 
            FOR XML PATH(''''),TYPE).value(''(./text())[1]'',''VARCHAR(MAX)''),1,1,''''),'''') AS WorkflowName
            from Client_1_Workflow wf WITH(NOLOCK)
```

Comment: These are not CTEs they are just 2 select statements. that are then using subselect in column definitions.  There are no joins on your selects but there are in your subselects.  Anyway, just copy the dynamic column from the second into the top 1, to get the delimited strings to be the same as they are now you will still need both subselects independently of trying to join anything

Comment: Just select ..., cOPF.WorkflowLinkID, mopfn.WorkflowName....  instead of LinkID in one statement and WorkflowName in another statement.   Going forward, it might be helpful if you simplified your example and clarified what the differences between the statements might be.

Comment: @missy his COALESCE(STUFF) dynamic columns are mechanisms to concatenate all of the rows within the query to a single (in this case) semi colon delimited string so changing anything in the sub selects would change the intent and value of the delimited strings. so Select...Work & Name doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT  wf.WorkflowID
                ,COALESCE(STUFF((
                SELECT distinct ''; '', '''' + cOPF.WorkflowLinkID
                FROM Client_1_Workflow mopf`enter code here`
                join Client_1_Workflow_Cell cOPF WITH(NOLOCK) on mopf.WorkflowID = cOPF.WorkflowLinkID
                join Client_1_Workflow iwf WITH(NOLOCK) on cOPF.WorkflowID = wf.WorkflowID
                where iwf.WorkflowID = wf.WorkflowID 
                FOR XML PATH(''''),TYPE).value(''(./text())[1]'',''VARCHAR(MAX)''),1,1,''''),'''') AS WorkflowID
              ,COALESCE(STUFF((
                SELECT distinct ''; '', '''' +mopfn.WorkflowName
                FROM Client_1_Workflow mopfn
                join Client_1_Workflow_Cell cOPF WITH(NOLOCK) on mopfn.WorkflowID = cOPF.WorkflowLinkID
                join Client_1_Workflow iwf WITH(NOLOCK) on cOPF.WorkflowID = wf.WorkflowID
                where iwf.WorkflowID = wf.WorkflowID 
                FOR XML PATH(''''),TYPE).value(''(./text())[1]'',''VARCHAR(MAX)''),1,1,''''),'''') AS WorkflowName
from Client_1_Workflow   wf WITH(NOLOCK)
```

This is a single query with your answer.  Without knowing what is a 1 to many, many to many, etc. it is impossible to determine how changing your concatenation would affect your desired results

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the intent in your question right, you want to append these to tables one on top of the other, then use the UNION ALL or UNION between the two CTE.  If this was not the intent of your question, please ignore.

```
CTE1
UNION ALL
CTE2;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
; WITH CTE1 AS
(
BLAH 
)
, CTE2 AS
(
BLAH BLAH
)
SELECT * FROM CTE1 JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.BLAH = CTE2.BLAH
```

Comment: that is how to join 2 ctes and is correct but the question is not about how to join the ctes but rather how to simplify the 2 queries to 1

Comment: @Matt I think he can figure out how to do it. if he knows how to use CTE's. If you feel it's not appropriate answer. I will delete it. (PS: I don't want to screw up my reputation. I am trying hard to achieve 50 pts to have a privilege to comment it.)